# Problem with cantilever beam and yield strength

Tags: structural-engineering, beam, yield-point

[image: Formula for cantilever beam with distributed equal force]

Hey, I make a project in which I use a cantilever beam with distributed equal load across the whole beam and I'm using the formulas above to calculate the displacement, moment...

My specifications for the beam are:
4.5m long aluminum 2024 beam, 4x3 cm walls (the force is applied on the 4cm side), 2mm thickness. and a young's modulus of 70 GPa. a force of 40 N/m is applied

from my calculations the moment of inertia is 37 mm^4, meaning the maximum displacement should be 0.6m at X=4.5 and the maximum moment is 400 N-m at X=0.

When I put the results in the formula for bending stress, the maximum bending stress is 162 MPa, while the yield stress for this type of aluminum is around 300 MPa.
 [image: Bending stress formula]

something here doesn't seems right for me. the beam is bent 0.6m but does not exceed the yield point, maybe I did a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I can see it bending that much - even a 3m length of copper pipe will form a nice curve if you load it gently.

Comment: I think you mean" deflection" . Al has a modulus 1/3 of steel so it deflects more than steel components . It is not affected by yield strength until you exceed the yield.

Comment: You are right, but it just seems really strange for me, the beam is bent 0.6 meters from it's original position but does not exceed the yield point?

Comment: Steel will tolerate 0.3 % elastic strain before yielding ( up to 0.6 % for high yield steel) . I don't know the number for Al.